# Stackin DIVs (possibly pure CSS) fixed-height and non fixed one

Tags: css, html, layout, fixed

i everybody!
I cannot figure out what is the best solution to obtain a layout like these:

+------------------------------------------------------------+

| div 0 , variable height

+------------------------------------------------------------+

| div 1 , variable height

+------------------------------------------------------------+

| div 2 , variable height

+------------------------------------------------------------+

| div 3 , fixed height

+------------------------------------------------------------+

| div 4, variable height, but must be scrollable (indeed contains table that should be scrollable)

+------------------------------------------------------------+

| div 5 , fixed height, sticked at bottom, always visible!

+------------------------------------------------------------+

i tried either  display: table/table-row and position absolute/relative solution but cannot obtain at all!

EDIT:
it would be also nice if the same behaviour is obtained by wrapping div3, div4, div5 into another div.

EDIT2: this is my solution
with `display:table`
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptQ4d/)

however, is it possible to make `div#cont` scrollable?

Thank you

Comment: Show us the code you have provided so far.

Comment: Try `position: fixed` for div 5 and `float: left; clear: both` for the div 0s. Make sure you have the `body` and `html` set to 100% height if you're going to make div 5 stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below css to fix the div bottom permanently..

```
div5

.fixed_footer{ position:fixed; height:20px; (you can change the value as you want it to be.) bottom:0; left:0; width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this??

http://jsfiddle.net/46fud/

HTML

```
<div class='commonDiv'>variable height<br>variable height</div>
<div class='commonDiv'>variable height<br>variable height</div>
<div class='commonDiv'>variable height<br>variable height</div>
<div class='div1'>fixed height</div>
<div class='div2'>fixed height, scrollable<br>fixed height, scrollable<br>fixed height, scrollable<br>fixed height, scrollable<br></div>    
<div class='div3'>fixed height at bottom</div>
```

CSS

```
.commonDiv{ float:left; width:100%; border:1px #000000 solid; }
.div1{float:left; height:50px; border:1px #000000 solid; width:100%;}
.div2{float:left; height:50px; overflow:scroll; border:1px #000000 solid; width:100%;}
.div3{position:fixed; bottom:0; height:50px; border:1px #000000 solid; width:100%;}
```

Comment: nearly perfect but, how can .div2 reach the top of .div3 without use javascript?

Comment: doesn't seems to work. how z-index could be useful? i mean, .div3 shuold not be over .div2, but simply after.